# What's an advantage of using Oracle PL/SQL XMLQUERY and XQuery instead of "EXTRACT(XML)"

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

It came to my attention that Oracle EXTRACT(XML) function is deprecated in Oracle 11g.

I used to make my XML processing by following approach:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE xmltype_table IS TABLE OF xmltype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  vt_xml_tab xmltype_table;
  v_xml      xmltype;
BEGIN
  --Generate simple XML document to pretend we received it by some interface
  SELECT xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select level, dbms_random.random rnd from dual connect by level<1000')) INTO v_xml FROM dual;

  --Get nodes
  SELECT VALUE(xm) xmlt BULK COLLECT INTO vt_xml_tab FROM TABLE(xmlsequence(v_xml.extract('/ROWSET/ROW/LEVEL'))) xm;

  --Do whatever processing I like
  FOR i IN 1..vt_xml_tab.count LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(vt_xml_tab(i).extract('LEVEL/text()').getstringval());
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Since EXTRACT is deprecated, Oracle suggests I should use XMLQUERY: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions060.htm

I would like to rewrite my previous processing as follows:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE xmltype_table IS TABLE OF xmltype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  vt_xml_tab xmltype_table;
  v_xml      xmltype;
BEGIN
  --Generate simple XML document to pretend we received it by some interface
  SELECT xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select level, dbms_random.random rnd from dual connect by level<1000'))
    INTO v_xml
    FROM dual;

  SELECT xmlquery('for $i in /ROWSET/ROW
      return $i/LEVEL' passing rowset_xml RETURNING content)
    INTO v_xml
    FROM (SELECT v_xml rowset_xml FROM dual);

  --Get nodes
  SELECT VALUE(xm) xmlt BULK COLLECT INTO vt_xml_tab FROM TABLE(xmlsequence(v_xml)) xm;

  --Do whatever processing I like
  FOR i IN 1 .. vt_xml_tab.count LOOP
    FOR x IN (SELECT extractvalue(vt_xml_tab(i), 'LEVEL') lvl FROM dual) LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(x.lvl);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

But it turns out that using XMLQUERY was significantly slower (0.8 vs 1.8 sec on my machine measuring by wall clock).

Is there a better way of not using EXTRACT function?

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
        SELECT 
        t.lvl, t.rnd
        FROM  
        XMLTABLE(
            '/ROWSET/ROW' PASSING (
            SELECT XMLTYPE(DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('select level, dbms_random.random rnd from dual connect by level<1000'))
                FROM Dual
            )
            COLUMNS 
                lvl NUMBER path 'LEVEL',
                rnd NUMBER path 'RND'
        ) t
    )
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.lvl || ' ' || rec.rnd);
    END LOOP ;
END ;
/
```